# How to get content via xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

On the web page i have

```
<meta name="description" content="Learn about 94.100.179.159" />
```

how can i get exactly the text "Learn about 94.100.179.159" via Xpath or HtmlAgilityPack

i've tried

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load("http://whois.domaintools.com/94.100.179.159");
            foreach (HtmlNode link in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta"))
            {
                string s = link.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(s);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

but that gives me not that i want, how to solve that?

Comment: this gives me HtmlAgilityPack.tmlAttribute ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta tags don't have any inner text, they have attributes.

Try this:

```
HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load("http://whois.domaintools.com/94.100.179.159");
foreach (HtmlNode link in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("-META-");
    var attribDump=link.Attributes.Select(a=>a.Name+" : "+a.Value);
    foreach (var x in attribDump)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you comment a little bit? what is "a" ? and why it's necessary to use second foreach loop?

Comment: @fen1ksss spender has used the linq `Select` extension method to project a new string `Name : Value` for each attribute found on meta elements, before dumping this projection to the console. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
//meta[@name = 'description']/@content
```

is the XPATH for the attribute you specified

```
string s = link.Value;
```

should return the attribute content.

Comment: there is no such parameter like link.Value

Comment: Try link.CreateNavigator().Value

Comment: nullreferenceexception was unhandled

Comment: Nick, I think that HAP is not a full XPath implementation and it doesn't implement the `attribute::` axis.

Answer (score 1):

Select the nodes as follows

```
SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='meta')]"))
```

Then, for each `HtmlNode`,

```
Console.WriteLine(link.Attributes["content"].Value);
```